# Errors with Converter Resource in XAML Page

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've implemented a custom converter class, and am trying to add it as a static resource to my Page object.  I've seen samples which use basically this exact syntax, but for Window rather than Page.  I feel like this is a simple typo but I've redone twice and cannot find the error.

Visual Studio underlines the `<Convert...` line with the error:   "All objects added to an IDictionary must have a Key attribute or some other type of key associated with them.", although I have added `x.Key=` on that very line.

**XAML**

```
xmlns:Convert="clr-namespace:solidTools.Converters"
<Page.Resources>
    <Convert:lengthConverter x.Key="LengthConvert" />
</Page.Resources>
```

**CS**

```
namespace solidTools.Converters
{
    public class lengthConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<Convert:lengthConverter x.Key="LengthConvert" />
```

should be

```
<Convert:lengthConverter x:Key="LengthConvert" />
```

note the x: should be a colon

Comment: ha!  of course.  I knew it was something simple, but didn't realize it was *that* simple.